# $_GET shows empty value

Tags: php

I have a `test.php` and i have the below code

```
<?php

    if(isset($_GET['p']) or $_GET['p'] != null) {
        echo $_GET['p'];
    } else {
        echo "Not found";
    }

?>
```

I have listed out below urls then required output are show

```
Test 1 : http://localhost/example/test.php
output : Notice: Undefined index: p in R:\xampp\htdocs\example\test.php on line 3
        Not found


Test 2 : http://localhost/example/test.php?p
output : blank page



Test 3 : http://localhost/example/test.php?p=
output : blank page


Test 4 : http://localhost/example/test.php?p=1
output : 1
```

I accept that `Test 1` and `Test 2` are `true`
But when `Test 2` and `Test 3` fails out the solution.

Comment: Which operators are better to use `and` or `||`

Comment: `and` = `&&` and `or` = `||` ..... [see here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

Comment: Rafee, they have different precedence, meaning that `or` and `||` behaves differently without parentheses in some cases. It's almost always better to use `&&` and `||` and use parentheses when needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<?php

if(!empty($_GET['p']))
    echo $_GET['p'];
else
    echo "Not found";
?>
```

Comment: This is the most correct since it's more obvious what's being done. Since `isset` already checks for NULL values, some people may be confused by the NULL check in other answers (which IS needed since it's a loose comparison, hence it's also checks for other "emptiness"). This is therefore the most readable and most maintainable answer!

Comment: Yeah! thanks @EmilVikström for brief comment to understand `why` and stefan for short code

Comment: Just keep in mind that it will print "Not found" for ...test.php?p=0 as well.

Comment: I've same problem. http://www.example.com/testing/test-diagram/?id=180. I used $id= $_GET['id'] get empty value. is their any issue with PHP version

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_GET['p']) and $_GET['p'] != null) {
    echo $_GET['p'];
} else {
    echo "Not found";
}
```

you need `and` as you want to check that it is set and is not null.

Like others have pointed out - you could use [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) :

```
if(!empty($_GET['p'])) {
    echo $_GET['p'];
} else {
    echo "Not found";
}
```

This will return `true` when the value is empty, the following is considered empty :

- `""` (an empty string)
- `0` (0 as an integer)
- `0.0` (0 as a float)
- `"0"` (0 as a string)
- `NULL`
- `FALSE`
- `array()` (an empty array)
- `var $var;` (a variable declared, but without a value in a class)

Comment: How strange - I could haev sworn that said or before and not and... doesn't show as an edit though :| Maybe another question did that was deleted? Hmm. Apologies!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    if(isset($_GET['p']) and $_GET['p'] != null) {
        echo $_GET['p'];
    } else {
        echo "Not found";
    }

?>
```

The above code you mentioned as `or` so it will take any one of the following as `true`
try with `and`

```
<?php

    if(isset($_GET['p']) and $_GET['p'] != null) {
        echo $_GET['p'];
    } else {
        echo "Not found";
    }

?>
```

And it will work perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an OR, so the second test will ALWAYS run. Meaning, if it's not set it will still try access it. You can use an AND instead (`&&`) so it will only check the value if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `empty()` instead of `isset()`.

```
<?php

if(empty($_GET['p'])) {
    echo "Not found";
} else {
    echo $_GET['p'];
}
```

Comment: No he can't, because it will produce undefined index on test1

Comment: Yes he can, because `empty()` does not warn about undefined vars and only returns `TRUE` if so.

Comment: `empty()` works since it's a language construct, not a function. Regular functions WOULD throw an error, but empty() and isset() is specifically made to not do that.

Comment: Try it and see.  Look at example #1 on this page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php